# What is the minimal common number probability distribution?

Tags: probability

There is a subset of natural numbers $\mathcal N=\{1,\ldots,N\}$ and there are four people who want to pick a number from that set $\mathcal N$.

How do we calculate the four independent probability distributions  $p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4$ on $\mathcal N$ (one for each person) that gives the minimum probability of the event $A = \{\text{any two or more of the persons picking the same number}\}$? Is it when all $p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4$ are i.i.d uniform?

Edit: The persons have no communication between them. They each pick the probability distribution individually. And there is no central authority giving them the distribution. After they pic the distributions they tell it to a central authority and that authority will calculate the probability of the event $A$.

Comment: I don't understand the question; do all four distributions have to be the same? else you could simply have each person deterministically pick a number, i.e. with probability $1$? And therefore the probability of collision is $0$?

Comment: @Shaktal The probability distributions do not have to be the same. But there is no central authority to tell them the distributions. So the idea of picking one number with probability one is  possible but one can not impose that the picked number is unique as there is no way for the person to know which number the other persons gave probability 1. Hope I made it clear. Thank you.

Comment: Suppose $N>3$. One such possibility would be for $p_1$ - certainly choose 1, for $p_2$ - certainly choose 2, etc. Are these allowed?

Comment: @Sasha they are certainly allowed but there is a problem because a third party cannot assign the probability distributions. The person has to find it alone. Thanks

Comment: If there is no communication or central authority, then why would any particular "distribution" make any difference, since from each person's perspective, the probability that any of the others will choose any of the numbers is $\frac1n$, where $n$ is the size of the subset? Unless I'm mistaken, the probability should be independent of the chosen distribution for each person individually.

Comment: @GlenO The probability of the event "two more more persons have the same number" depends on the probability distributions $p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4$. For instance if they all take with probability 1 the number $k$ then the event has probability 1 too. On the other hand if they each take i.i.d. uniform distribution then the probability of the interested event is less than 1. Isn't that the case? Thank you

Comment: @triomphe, it depends on the probability distributions, but for each person, without knowledge of the other distributions, the probabilities can effectively be set equal to $\frac1n$.

Comment: Think of it this way - you suppose that they all choose the number $k$ with probability 1, and this proves that the chance of the event can be 1. And it can. But they have no way to know which number the others will choose, and thus the probability that any two have chosen the same $k$ is $\frac1n$. So as I said, the probability that any two will choose the same number is $\frac1n$.

Comment: @GlenO Now I understand your argument. So that tells us they each use a uniform distrbuiton of the set of number, isn't that so? Thank you.

Comment: @triomphe, they needn't use a uniform distribution, but each person can treat the others' distributions as uniform. As such, a choice of distribution makes no difference to the result, as far as each person is concerned, although the real probability will depend on the specific distributions. If each one chooses a different number with probability 1, then the probability of the event is zero, which is minimal. But with the knowledge available to the people, the probability of a particular pair matching is $\frac1n$.

Comment: @GlenO I think there is a bit of confusion here. The result is not what each person things is the probability of the event $A$. The result is unique. It's like after they decide on their own distribution then they tell it to some central authority and then he tell them the probability of event $A$. So it's one value.

Comment: @triomphe, so you're not asking to find the minimal result, but merely what the probability is?

Comment: @GlenO Yes. What should be the distributions they tell the authority :)

Comment: @triomphe, as I said, with the information that each person has available to them, they cannot know what distributions to tell the authority. Think of it this way - if $p_1$ and $p_2$ both choose a probability of 1 of a single value, then there is a $\frac1n$ chance that those single values will be the same single value. So the authority has a $\frac1n$ chance of saying that the probability of the event is 1, and a $\frac{n-1}n$ chance of saying it has a probability of 0.

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the probability of two specific people choosing the same number, given their chosen distributions, we simply add up the probabilities of each pair matching, like this...

Supposing that $p_k(n)$ is the probability that person $k$ chooses $n$ (so $p_k$ is the distribution for person $k$), then the probability that they match is
$$
P_{j,k} = \sum_{i=1}^N p_j(i) p_k(i)
$$
These can then be extended, to determine the probabilities for three or four, and thus the probability that at least two match can be found by inclusion/exclusion.

However, if each person is unable to have any knowledge of any other person's distribution, then it can easily be seen that the *expected* probabilities (as reported by the authority) are $P_{j,k} = \frac1n$, where $n$ is the size of the subset being used. Similarly, $P_{i,j,k}=\frac1{n^2}$ and $P_{i,j,k,l} = \frac1{n^3}$. The expected probability that at least two match can then be found by inclusion/exclusion, as noted above.

Comment: Could you please have a look at Ragnar's answer. That is more intuitive to me and I was thinking along that line. Is your answer the same in a different argument? thanks for the answer.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in answering. Our answers are somewhat different. Where mine focuses on expected probabilities, Ragnar's focuses on highest probability. Think of it this way - if each person chooses a specific number with probability 1, then depending on the specific numbers, the probability of two choosing the same number is either 0 or 1. The maximum of these is 1, and thus is clearly suboptimal. However, the expected probability will always be $\frac1n$ for any pair of people, irrespective of the distribution designs themselves.

Answer (score 1):

There is a set of all possible distributions $D$. Each person has it's own probability distribution on this set (so for each distribution, there is a probability a player will choose it). Because all players are identical, these distributions are too. The distribution of the numbers a player will choose can now be calculated (by taking a weighted average of the probabilities in the distributions in $D$). Because $D$ and the distributions over $D$ are identical, so is the final distribution for each player. Thus we conclude that all players have identical distributions. Now, it is not hard to prove the identical distribution with probability $\frac 1n$ for each number is optimal.

**EDIT**
Suppose the probabilities for the numbers are $p_1$, $p_2$, $\dots$, $p_n$, with $\sum_{i=1}^np_i=1$. If $p_1<p_2$ (or $p_i<p_j$ for some $i$ and $j$) the probability that two (chosen) players 'collide' on $1$ or $2$ is $p_1^2+p_2^2$. (This is not the probability that two out of the five players collide, but this is sufficient to show that $\frac 1n$ is optimal.) We know that $p_1^2+p_2^2\geq 2\left(\frac {p_1+p_2}2\right)^2$ (because of the quadratic-arithmetic mean on $p_1$ and $p_2$). Thus, it is better to replace $p_1$ and $p_2$ by their average. Now, if follows (intuitively) that it is optimal to have all $p_i$ equal, and thus equal to $\frac 1n$.

Comment: I understand your argument up to the point where you say probability $1/n$ is optimal? Can we be sure that there is no other distribution that gives same result at this uniform distribution? Thank you.